# Can I Check in folder with history to the another TFS

Tags: tfs

I have one folder in TFS1, I want check in this folder to the another TFS i.e TFS2 with **history**. Is there any easy way?

Both TFS are 2012 only, but in different machines. Here history is very important for me.

Regards,
Rajendar.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Integration tools

http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe